# Where can I download precompiled GTK+ 3 binaries or windows installer?

Tags: windows, gtk, gtk3

I have taken a look at GTK+3 and I like it. But unfortunately compiling from source has never worked for me. Is there any okace with decent binaries or even better, a windows installer?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**2020-03-19 update:**

GTK+ dropped the + and their website has been rewritten. So the install instructions for GTK on Windows are now at https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/

**2017-04-07 update:**

To make it clear, since 2017-06-23, the GTK+ project doesn't provide binary bundles for Windows. These are now provided by the MSYS2 project, with the blessing of the GTK+ team.

MSYS2 provides the most up-to-date versions of GTK+ for Windows, as well as a complete toolchain, and other useful GTK-related development tools like:

- **Glade**, the GUI designer
- **Devhelp**, the offline documentation browser

The official GTK+ website contains [GTK+ installation instructions for Windows](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php).

**2013-10-27 update:**

There's now an officially supported version of GTK 3 for Windows (GTK 3.6.4 as of today). You'll find it on the [official GTK+ website](http://www.gtk.org), in the *Downloads* section.
Thanks to the GTK team, and to tarnyko for his work in this regard.

**2013-02-01 update:**

There's a French dude (tarnyko) providing an [(unofficial) GTK 3 installer for Windows](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/20), based on the OpenSUSE binaries, and another guy providing [another (unofficial, again) build](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2012-December/msg00046.html). Might help. The [gtk-list](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list) mailing list is the best place to check how this evolves through time.

**2011-05-15 original content:**

There is currently no installer for GTK3 on Windows. However, the OpenSUSE Build System provides the [Windows binaries for GTK3](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Factory/noarch/). On a [GTK3 on Windows](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2011-March/msg00057.html) thread of the GTK devel mailing list, Maarten Bosmans provided the [download-mingw-rpm.py](http://www.bosmans.ch/pulseaudio/download-mingw-rpm.py) python script, which automates the download of a package and its dependencies, and then uses 7-zip to unzip the content of the packages. See the post he explains [how to use download-mingw-rpm.py](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-mingw/2011-03/msg00020.html).

Comment: The downloaded result looks terrible and it is far far away from the convenience of the previously provided binary builds. If this is the only way - then calling it a platform independent toolkit is an euphemism.

Comment: GTK3 is pretty new, and the GTK+ for Windows maintainer has recently stopped his activity... Nobody stepped forward to create a new installer for the moment, so GTK3 on Windows works, but I admit that installation on Windows is difficult for the time being.

Comment: Gave another try today and downloaded with that script the whole thing. It installs nicely in fact, with python >= python 3.2 (3.0 failed for me), and a recent version of 7-zip. However, running gtk3-demo was a bit disapointing, as I had a good amount of crashes. I still need to sort out if it's my installation that is at fault, gtk3-demo, or GTK3 itself.

Comment: The python script is not working with python 2.6.6, i guess i should install 3.2 then. It does seem disappointing that an awesome cross-platform toolkit like Gtk has almost no , or incomplete windows binaries. I am currently trying the OpenSuse build. Thanks all. :)

Comment: As I said just above, it requires at least python 3.2...

Comment: Some [GTK on Windows](http://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2011/11/25/gtk-work-on-windows) development happened. For GTK2, the best release for the time being is now GTK 2.24.8, and some GTK3 fixes should appear in GTK 3.6.

Comment: These windows binaries are definitly not stable. I've tested them on my code, but even the gtk-demo crashes if you click to much.

Comment: Which binaries are you taking about (version) ?

Comment: Looks like it might be solved in a few month, as 3.4 contains a lot. And again i was more realistic then most young OSS Fanboys - i predicted it will take upto 2 years until ported to Windows, it's now 13 month.

Comment: I was wrong, it's still not solved and it's now 6 years later.

Comment: What lets you think it's not solved ? I've been playing with GTK on Windows for the last month. Those are pre-compiled binaries installed using MSYS2.

Comment: Or you're talking about the stability ?

Comment: As of Nov 2023, [Sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk-mingw/files/gtk%2B3/) also seems to be providing Gtk3 binaries along with related binaries like Glade, etc.

Comment: @PrahladYeri: Those binaries were made by a third party, provided on a website with a bad security history in the pas few years, and are from 2012 which was more than 10 years ago (so you don't get the features, bug fixes and security fixes of the last 10 years). Don't use them.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that proper Windows port is coming soon. According to this gnome developer blogpost:

http://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2011/11/25/gtk-work-on-windows/

and it's comment section, Windows binaries should be available in near time.

Comment: Thank God. In desperation, I had resorted to Java Swing. Now I can finally return to good old GTK.

Answer (score 6):

There's a GTK+ 3.4.2 Windows binary installer available here :

http://www.tarnyko.net/?q=node/1

With a development version containing libraries, headers, MinGW & Vala compilers at the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sharing the latest GTK+ and gtkmm binaries for Windows 32-bit through DropBox.
[Take a look.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8d1qbh5dsp044on/UgkALzhlqH)
3.22.0 for GTK+ and 3.22.0 for gtkmm as of today.

Comment: I'm interested to know how you produced these binaries.  Can you share so I can do compilation magic of my own?

Comment: @Relish Of course. Click [here](https://github.com/Wesley-Chan/GTK-for-Windows).

Answer (score 2):

This one is even fatter and wholesome, but targeted for pygi. GTK is version 3.6.4 http://opensourcepack.blogspot.com/p/pygobject-pygi-aio.html. BTW i'm former windows build mypaint maintainer which migrate to pygobject 3. Also for MinGW i'm providing the most badass MinGW distro http://opensourcepack.blogspot.com/p/tuma-mingw.html