# Where to get windows binaries for gtk-sharp3

Tags: windows, gtk#

Similar to [this question about GTK+ 3 for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006689/where-can-i-download-precompiled-gtk-3-binaries-or-windows-installer), is there any place that offers compiled GTK# bindings for Windows? I searched for a while and can't find any official releases (which makes sense since there are no official GTK3 releases for Windows either), but also neither Banshee nor Xamarin come with GTK(#)-3.

I'm also unsure if [these instructions for compiling GTK# 2 on Windows](http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_GtkSharp) are still valid, but the page doesn't provide an awful lot of detail, so I guess it'll take half a day to figure out of it works that way.

Any other place where I might find the GTK# 3 binaries for Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the c# binding for GTK3 from:

https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/releases

This includes a windows installer.

These bindings are pre release and are versioned as Gtk# 2.99.3

My understanding is that the version will change to 3.0 when it is released as stable.

Comment: I don't think it was there when I asked the question, but it's good to finally have the question answered!