# GTK3 and Python3 on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, gtk3

Is there any way to launch a Python3 / GTK3 based application on a Windows machine? It seems that this is not that simple as with GTK2/Python2.

Thanks a lot,
Thomas

Comment: Maybe here https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php

Answer (score 2):

I hope, i understand the question. You Need a actual runtime of gtk3 on Windows.

inofficial gtk3.14.13 64bit-Runtime, 32bit here not available,
see:
 https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer

win32 and win64: experimental official runtime 3.6.4  in http://www.gtk.org/download/index.php 
is very Alpha or beta.

I hope this helps enough for gtk3.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are still [no *official* GTK3 or GObject-Introspection libraries for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006689/), and so there are no python bindings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want the development kit. Windows version has indeed been missing for a long time, but there's some available now.

Going to official site and finding https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject, you can find a link to "Windows installers" which should lead to a rather massive all-in-one installer for Gtk3 and many related libraries for Python 3. You can load a current cpython from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and install that first.

For windows, there's also a lot of unofficial pre-built packages in http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Cpython 3.4 at least seems to include a functional pip for installing wheels.

I've made some use of these for running some python and matplotlib code 64-bit windows and they work rather nicely with 64-bit python 3.4. You can test with e.g. http://gtk3-matplotlib-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ to find backend settings and other tips.