# Cant install glib on Windows when trying to install gtk3 using cabal

Tags: haskell, gtk, cabal, cabal-install, haskell-platform

I have been trying to install gtk3 with cabal, following instructions on https://wiki.haskell.org/Gtk2Hs/Installation , with the exception I have replace gtk with gtk3, I downloaded the all in one bundle of gtk 3.6.4 (from: http://www.tarnyko.net/dl/gtk.htm) unzip it and added the location_of_files/bin to my path, running pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 works ok, cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools correctly installs, but cabal install gtk3 stops with:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring glib-0.13.4.1...
Failed to install glib-0.13.4.1
Build log ( C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\glib-0.13.4.1.log ):
cabal: Entering directory 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-6472\glib-0.13.4.1'
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-6472\glib-0.13.4.1\dist\setup\setup.hs, C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-6472\glib-0.13.4.1\dist\setup\Main.o )
Linking C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-6472\glib-0.13.4.1\dist\setup\setup.exe ...
Configuring glib-0.13.4.1...
setup.exe: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: intl
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-6472\glib-0.13.4.1'
```

And the gtk bundle I download have a libintl.h file in the include folder and a dll in the bin folder, I tried placing the files in almost every location I could think of but to no avail, i can’t think of anything else.

More details: I am running windows 7 x64 with haskell-platform 8.0.2 x64, and I really need this to work under windows for a project I am working.

Comment: That library is part of gettext (https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html) and you could try installing gettext to make sure it works and all its own dependencies are satisfied.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662215/how-do-you-install-gtk-3-0-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

I manage to install gtk by following the instruction in https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php, installing MSYS2 and using pacman to install gtk library, ignoring only step 4. After installing the libraries I added to my path C:\msys64\mingw64\bin, and cabal finally compiled gtk3.
I did not like this solution cause it is one more mingw installation on my pc.

Comment: I think you could re-use an existing MSYS2 installation and just installing the missing packages.