# Trouble setting up GTK+ for C++ Development

Tags: c++, gtk

I have created an `example.cpp` file in Visual Studio which very simply has one line:

`#include <gtk/gtk.h>`

I am getting the following error:

`cannot open source file "gtk/gtk.h"`

---

Here are the steps I took to setup GTK+.

I downloaded the latest stable version of GTK+ from http://win32builder.gnome.org/ choosing `gtk+-bundle_3.10.4-20131202_win64.zip`.

I then followed `gtk+-bundle_3.10.4-20131202_win64.README.txt` with the following instructions.

To summarise:

1. I added the `bin` folder to my path
2. Ensured there was no prior version of GTK+ on the system
3. Prepared Pango, GDK-Pixbuf and GTK+IMModules
4. Verified it worked by running `gtk3-demo`
5. Verified it was in the system by running `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` with the output:

`-mms-bitfields -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/include/gtk-3.0 -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/include/cairo -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/include/pango-1.0 -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/include/atk-1.0 -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/include/cairo -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/include/pixman-1 -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/include -I/srv/win32builder/fixed_3104/build/win64/include/freetype2 -I/srv/win32builder/fixed_3104/build/win64/include/libxml2 -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/include/libxml2 -I/srv/win32builder/fixed_3104/build/win64/include/freetype2 -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/include/libpng16 -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/include/libpng16 -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/include/glib-2.0 -IE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/lib/glib-2.0/include -LE:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -lz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl`

where `E:/Developer/external/gtk-3.10.4_win64` is where  I have extracted the GTK files to.

Comment: How are you building?

Comment: @andlabs Just through Visual Studio's default Build -> Build Solution menu option.

Comment: In that case, what are your project settings?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure which settings you mean, or where to find them. Could you describe a bit more what you're looking for?

Comment: Don't use those builds they are ancient. Look into something like https://github.com/wingtk/gtk-win32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2020-03-19 update:**

This answer is old, I update that story on:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6008390/518853

**Original content:**

These builds are old. You should avoid getting your GTK+ binaries from random sources. The official way is documented on the official GTK+ website: https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php

You're supposed to install MSYS2 which provides a whole lot of open-source packages for Windows. It uses the pacman package manager, which then allows you to install GTK+ 3. It always has the most up-to date version of GTK+ 3 (3.22.7-1 provided in MSYS2 as the date I'm writing).